# Calculating the population for 10 years later

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with one column named (population of 2018).
lets suppose that the pop of 2018 is 25 million.

I want to add one more column which represent the population of the year 2028; which is ten years later from now.

If the increase percentage of the population is 3% every year, how to calculate the population for 2028?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming question. Please see what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].  This might be better suited to [the Math Forum](http://mathforum.org/dr/math/).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If cell A1 holds data then your formula should be:

`=A1*(1+0.03)^10`

Comment: Please see [“Why shouldn't I answer off-topic questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262573/8112776).  (More at [answer].)

Comment: It seems your formula is correct. Can you please explain it or give more clarification on it.

Comment: Please check compound interest on the net which will explain the calculation.

Answer (score -1):

You should have to find out the population of last 50 to 100 year and then see how much population is increasing from last 10 year.
for example if the population in 1988 is 10 million and in 1998 it will become 13 million and then in 2008 become 18 million and in 2018 it will become 28 million.

- in 1998, population is increased by 30 percent.
- in 2008, population is increased by 38 percent.
- in 2018, population is increased by 55 percent.

so from the above data we can say that in 2028 population will increase approximately 82 to 85 percent that will be 51 million.